# How to get the count of Custom tuples against two lists

Tags: python, tuples, counter, slice, iterable

Please help me to get the counter for the list SS2 in list SS1 in PYTHON using from collections import Counter or any other fastest way

```
SS1 = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]

SS2=[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5),
(1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 6),
(3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6), (3, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Here is what i have tried and i don't know how to get the count for (1,2,4) th elements of the each tuple

```
SS1=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(elem[0:3] for elem in SS1[0:6])

for k, v in c.items():
    if (v > 0):
        print(k,v)
```

Now this is running perfect for 0:3 but what i want is to get the count for not 1,2,3 but i want for 1,2,4 the elements count for each tuple.

Sorry guys hope you understand my question...sorry again i'm new this python.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit by adding the expected output for this input?

Comment: What is it that you want to accomplish?

Comment: from collections import Counter
c = Counter(elem[0:3] for elem in SS1[0:6])

for k, v in c.items():
    if (v > 0):
        print(k,v)


This gives only for the below values

(1, 2, 3) 3
(1, 2, 4) 1
(1, 3, 4) 1
(2, 3, 4) 1


but i want to know for all the values in my second set SS2

Comment: Please add expected output to the question, not the comments. Also, what do you mean by custom tuple?

Comment: or just let me know how to specify in elem[0:3]  for the silice(2,3,5)

Comment: no one really understands what you are trying to say. Post what you want as output

Comment: @s_vishnu ok in simple terms pls get me the count of (1,4,5) in list SS1

Comment: @JohnEbenezer Take a look at my answer and see if that's what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the count of elements of tuples of your own...not just the range or sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494022/get-the-count-of-elements-of-tuples-of-your-own-not-just-the-range-or-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am assuming what you want as your output here as you weren't clear. So basically what you want is to find the count of *items* in SS1 in SS2.

e.g. The number of times `(1,4,5)` occuring in SS1

Which would be **3** i.e in `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`,`(1, 2, 4, 5, 6)`,`(1, 3, 4, 5, 6)`

so for `(1, 2, 5)` it would be **3** again right? present in
`(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),(1, 2, 3, 5, 6),(1, 2, 4, 5, 6)`

I think what you might need is.

```
set(tuple2).issubset(tuple1)
```

So here is a code for your problem:

```
SS1 = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
SS2=[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5),
(1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 6),
(3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6), (3, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6)]
count=0
count_list = []
for ss2item in SS2:
    for ss1item in SS1:
        if set(ss2item).issubset(ss1item):
            count+=1
    count_list.append(count)        
    count=0
print(count_list)
```

It's output would be a list of count for each items in SS2:

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempl and it's not really that what i want and the way u suggest may not be a fastest in python as i'm processing millions of records...so counter would be the best coice...Thanks buddy

Comment: Okay then will give a solution if you be clear in specifying the output. But the output is correct right?

Comment: u can see the answer i post here and i can't choose my one as a answer and seems need to wait for two days

Answer (score -1):

credit to @Chiheb Nexus

```
SS1=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]

from collections import Counter

def get_new_list(a, pos):
    # Check if any element in pos is > than the length of the tuples
    if any(k >= len(min(SS1, key=lambda x: len(x))) for k in pos):
        return

    for k in a:
        yield tuple(k[j] for j in pos)

def elm_counter(elm):
    if not len(elm):
        return 

    c = Counter(elm)
    for k, v in c.items():
        if v > 0:
            print(k, v)
elm = list(get_new_list(SS1, (2,)))
elm_counter(elm)
print('---')    
elm = list(get_new_list(SS1, (0, 2, 3)))
elm_counter(elm)
print('---')
elm = list(get_new_list(SS1, (1, 3, 4)))
elm_counter(elm)
```

Comment: I don't know if this can accepted as an answer or not. I think you should delete this question because it's a duplicate from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494022/get-the-count-of-elements-of-tuples-of-your-own-not-just-the-range-or-sequence)