# get the count of elements of tuples of your own...not just the range or sequence

Tags: python, collections, tuples, counter, slice

The below code is running for first three elements of the tuple of this list

```
SS1=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(elem[0:3] for elem in SS1)

for k, v in c.items():
    if (v > 0):
        print(k,v)
```

and the output is:

```
(1, 2, 3) 3
(1, 2, 4) 1
(1, 3, 4) 1
(2, 3, 4) 1
```

But my expectation is not just for first three tuple...i want the counter for tuple `(0,2,3)` or tuple `(1,2,4)` likewise i can pass any three position of the tuple and get the count of it... How can I do this?

Comment: remove the `[0:3]`?

Comment: Where does `(0,2,3)` come from? There isn't a `0` in `SS1`

Comment: Does that tuple have to exist in a contiguous manner in the tuple-list?

Comment: A few general points, your comprehension is no necessary `c = Counter(SS1[:3])` would be the same; `Counter`s can't contain non-positive values, so `v > 0` check is unnecessary

Comment: (0,2,3) is just a possible 3 combinations of a set {0,1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: @ Sachin Kukreja : YES

Comment: @ Chris_Rands...Yep u r right bro...TRUE

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks for the edit and removing [0:3] would throw invalid syntax

Comment: @JohnEbenezer On my machine it does not but I still do not quite understand what it is that you want.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis...in simple terms pls get me the count for (1,4,5)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis in elem[0:3] how to specify any three position of my tuple...not range

Comment: @Chiheb Nexus - Thanks bro and such a great solution and exactly that's what i want and i'm so happy and it's 100% working and it my first asking in stack u make my day today. Ton's of Thanks. And thanks everyone in line...Thank u all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what i understood from your question is correct, the code below will solve your issue:

```
SS1=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]

from collections import Counter

def get_new_list(a, pos):
    # Check if any element in pos is > than the length of the tuples
    if any(k >= len(min(SS1, key=lambda x: len(x))) for k in pos):
        return

    for k in a:
        yield tuple(k[j] for j in pos)

def elm_counter(elm):
    if not len(elm):
        return 

    c = Counter(elm)
    for k, v in c.items():
        if v > 0:
            print(k, v)

elm = list(get_new_list(SS1, (0, 2, 4)))
elm_counter(elm)
print('---')
elm = list(get_new_list(SS1, (1, 2, 4)))
elm_counter(elm)
```

Output:

```
(1, 3, 5) 1
(1, 3, 6) 2
(1, 4, 6) 2
(2, 4, 6) 1
---
(2, 3, 6) 2
(2, 3, 5) 1
(3, 4, 6) 2
(2, 4, 6) 1
```

Comment: Wow...what a great solution and U r the MAN and make my day today!!! Thanks u so much for such a great help and it's my first asking and i was literally happy with the solution that u provide and Thank u so much bro. Ton's of thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. If my solution fills your needs you can upvote it and accept it (check the green box under the votes of the answer).

Comment: Yep...Just done and i didn't even know how to pass the credits to u officially here it's my very first asking with stack...i send a email also to u pls be in touch i need your help in the future too...Thanks a lot!!! U R absolutely great.

Comment: Accepting my answer is a way to thank me :-) Have a nice day and happy coding.

Comment: how to ask something only to u but not on forum...i mean any doubt or soemthing

Comment: Ask it into Stackoverflow. Me or anyone else will try to answer you.

Comment: how about passing one argument...just only one. elm = list(get_new_list(SS1, (2)))
elm_counter(elm)

Comment: instead of using `(1, 2, 4)` use `(1,)` or `[1]` and the code will run. The point is passing an iterable as argument.

Comment: Great...Thanks a lot.