# Find the previous index value of each tuple element in the list using python

Tags: python

I need to find the previous index value of each element of the tuples.

```
SS1=[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 6), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6), (3, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6)]
```

In the fist tuple 1,2,3 the 1 occurs in the next tuple itself and 2 also in next tuple and 3 was not occur in any of the tuple in that position so that is 0...so now the answer is 1,1,0

and for the second tuple 1,2,4, and the 1 present in the next tuple and 2 also in the same next tuple and 4 present in 3rd tuple so the answer goes 1,1,3

Expected out put for the above list would be like this `[(1,1,0),(1,1,3), ...]`

Element position must follow as it is. In the same position no cross look up.

Comment: Why for the second tuple why it is (1, 1, 3)? Is 4 present in the 3rd tuple? It is in the fifth tuple.

Comment: @Nurzhan: OP doesn't mean that `4` is represented in the 3rd tuple, but that it is represented int he 3rd tuple from the second tuple, i.e. that `4` is in the 3rd index of the third tuple from the current (i.e. second) tuple in `SS1`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Ok. This is what I thought.

Comment: You have asked this question 3 times with slighjtly different wording.
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494022/get-the-count-of-elements-of-tuples-of-your-own-not-just-the-range-or-sequence
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491784/how-to-get-the-count-of-custom-tuples-against-two-lists

Comment: @kdopen...i'm newbie to python and just a few weeks old and currently running some huge sales forecast application so will be keep asking in the same routine...i'm sorry abt that...all my giggling is in an around tuples only...what to do...sometimes fate...Keep going bro....i'm not wasting time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach (though it may not be the fastest):

```
SS1 = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 6), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6), (3, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6)]

answer = []
for idx, t in enumerate(SS1):
    offsets = [None]*len(t)
    for i, n in enumerate(t):
        for offset,tup in enumerate(itertools.islice(SS1, idx+1, len(SS1)), 1):
            if tup[i] == n:
                offsets[i] = offset
                break
    offsets = [0 if os is None else os for os in offsets]
    answer.append(tuple(offsets))
```

Output:

```
In [12]: answer
Out[12]: [(1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 3), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 6), 
          (1, 1, 2), (1, 4, 2), (1, 1, 4), (1, 5, 1), (0, 6, 3), 
          (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 2), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), 
          (0, 3, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0)]
```

You could improve it with some preprocessing with a dictionary, if you really wanted to improve the runtime at linear space cost

Comment: Wow...This is what exactly i want and i'm not thinking the speed now but i'm going to use your line of codes. any improvisation pls suggest me and i'm few weeks old newbie to python. sorry about that. Thanks for your great great help. u guys are rocking.

Comment: sorry bro i myself find it for idx, t in enumerate(ListToFind): and the other line to for offset,tup in enumerate(itertools.islice(ListToCompare, idx+1, len(ListToCompare)), 1):

Comment: Bro...can pls help on For each item k,v in this dict, where all values v are tuples, I need to subtract the k value from all values in tuple v."

Comment: is not related to this answer

Comment: @JohnEbenezer: If it's not related to this question, I'd recommend posting a new question

Comment: fine and i my self have find it already v[:] = [x - k for x in v]

Answer (score 0):

The fastest approach is to go backwards through the list, keeping an ongoing list of the latest mention of a given number:

```
def previous_index(SS1):
    answer = []
    last_reference = [dict(), dict(), dict()]
    input_rev = SS1.copy()
    input_rev.reverse()
    for idx, tup in enumerate(input_rev):
        answer_tup = []
        for t_idx, value in enumerate(tup):
            if value in last_reference[t_idx]:
                answer_tup.append(last_reference[t_idx][value])
                last_reference[t_idx][value] = idx
            else:
                answer_tup.append(0)
                last_reference[t_idx][value] = 0
        answer.append(tuple(answer_tup))
    answer.reverse()
    return answer
```

edited: I misunderstood the question and had thought that the location in the tuple didn't matter. It now works as specified, and works in O(n) time.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but the location is the key...pls look into that nd reply...i need to process against millions of records...pls help

Comment: Ah, please excuse the lack of clarity, I have fixed it and it now works as specified. Same results as @inspectorG4dget's but in O(n) time.

Comment: Great, Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do this (in one line):

```
list(map(tuple,zip(*[[item.index(r,idx+1)-idx if r in item[idx+1:] else 0 for idx,r in enumerate(item)] for item in list(map(list, zip(*SS1)))])))
```

Here, I considered SS1 as a matrix, transposed it to get three lists containing all the first elements, second elements and third elements respectively.

Then, I found the index of next occurrence of each element and replaced the three lists with those values.
Finally, transposed the matrix back to original, and converted the inner lists to a tuple